# How to write a for loop with forms in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, for-loop

I'm new to JS.

I want to write a for-loop in JS that gives out a chosen number of forms. 
This is what I got so far. (Maybe I have to write a function. But I have no clue how to continue.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>Survey</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="survey.css">
  </head>
  <body>


<h1><?php echo "Title: ".$_POST["title"];
?></h1>


<script>

    var Ausgabe = "";
      for (var i = 1; i <= <?php echo $_POST["anzahl"];?>; i++){
            Ausgabe = i + ". question: " + <form>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title"> 
    </form>
    document.write(Ausgabe)
    }

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to put your strings in quotes, resulting in syntax errors.  You would also be producing invalid HTML by re-using the same `id`.

Comment: you want form value to the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with JavaScript:

```
var Ausgabe = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= <?php echo $_POST["anzahl"];?>; i++){
        Ausgabe = i + ". question: " + "<form><input type=\"text\" id=\"title\" name=\"title\"></form>"
document.write(Ausgabe)
}
```

Adding quotes around the "html" string and escaping the quotes inside it (like type=\"text\").

Anyway I think should be better do the loop directly via PHP, something like:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= anzahl; $i++) {
    echo "<form><input type=\"text\" id=\"title\" name=\"title\"></form>";
}
```

I hope it helps, bye.

Comment: Oh sure, it would be better, both on text and form, anyway in his code there aren't ids.

Comment: you are writing forms with inputs which have ID attributes

Comment: Thanks, a lot, this works. @happymacarts: This is a great idea but it doesn't work with my code. It says unexpected token. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your goals are, but I think you are trying to do something like this:

```js
var input = prompt('Enter a number (<= 10):'),
    html = '';

if (Number(input) <= 10) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Number(input); i++) {
    html += '<form>';
    html += '  <input type="text" placeholder="' + i + '">';
    html += '</form>';
  }
} else {
  console.log('The number is too high!');
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```